# Detox/Appium tap, multiTap, and longPress not working on element

Tags: react-native, appium, detox

Using detox with a React Native project. Here is the component:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
  testID={'rss_list_' + this.props.index}
  onPress={this.selectItem}
>
  <View testID={'rss_list_text_' + this.props.index}>
    <Text style={styles.itemText}>
      {this.props.item.title ? this.props.item.title.trim() : "no title"}
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

The actual test:

```
  it('should have an Rss List', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('RssList'))).toExist();
  });

  it('should have a Header', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('main_header'))).toExist();
  });

  it('should have a populated rss list', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('rss_list_populated'))).toExist();
  });

  it('should have an rss item', async () => {
    await expect(element(by.id('rss_list_2'))).toBeVisible();
  });

  it('should tap on the rss item', async () => {
    await element(by.id('rss_list_2')).tap();
  });

  it('should see the item view', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id('item_view'))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(10000);
  });
```

The issue:

should have an rss item succeeds and the item is found.
However trying to tap on the TouchableWithoutFeedback, View, or Text element succeeds but the function underneath doesn't fire. The test does not fail Detox says that the Tap happened however the item_view which results from the Tap never comes into view. I have tried all the methods in the title: tap, multiTap, and longPress. I have also tried tapping manually during the test and it also doesn't work. Are only some elemnt types tap-able in detox?

Update: I tried in Appium today and it also could not click on the element. It looks like the issue is with **TouchableWithoutFeedback**

Answer (score 0):

`TouchableWithoutFeedback` does not support the `testID` prop and neither will the `View` directly underneath.